# PhpStorm not stopping at breakpoints Xdebug

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I am trying to debug a Yii2 project using Xdebug.

Before formatting the MacOS, I just entered the web project(Apache 2 web server) from browser and PhpStorm was automatically stopping at breakpoints. Now I have set up everything but PhpStorm does not stop at them.

Here is the PhpStorm validation of debugger:

[image]

Here is CLI interpreter (php 7.0 executable)

[image]

Here is the IDE key for xdebug:

[image]

I have installed the Xdebug Chrome extension, and it is in debug mode.

What I am missing? What may be the cause that PhpStorm does not stop at breakpoints?

Comment: Have you tried this [Xdebug Setup](https://gist.github.com/odan/1abe76d373a9cbb15bed) ?

Comment: What Xdebug log has to say? Maybe you have somehow installed php-fpm (when you were doing your "I have set up everything") .. and now it tries to connect there? Try changing xdebug port to be 9001 in both php.ini and PhpStorm settings.

Comment: This solved my problem. Please move the comment to answer section so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Before formatting the MacOS, I just entered the web project (Apache 2 web server) from browser and PhpStorm was automatically stopping at breakpoints. Now I have set up everything but PhpStorm does not stop at them.

There is a big chance that you may have installed too much stuff. I mean -- something that you unaware of or how it works.

Right now it sounds like it might be **php-fpm** -- it also uses `TCP 9000` port that Xdebug uses by default ... so when Xdebug is making debug connection to IDE it connects to php-fpm instead (and PhpStorm cannot detect on Mac that such port is already in use).

Therefore: please change Xdebug port to be some another number (e.g. `9001` should be fine) in both php.ini and PhpStorm settings.

Answer (score 2):

As XDebug is being shown as loaded in your PHPSotmr config, you already have the `zend_extension = "/path/to/xdebug.so"` in your php.ini.

Chances are you don't have the other required settings in php.ini.

Check the following values are set in your php.ini:

```
xdebug.remote_autostart=On
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

Comment: This answer saved me, I had the ports correct but was missing remote_enable and remote_autostart. Thank you!